# Criteria from join two tables Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, criteria

I have 2 entity
BlackList

```
public class BlackList {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "applicant_id", unique = true)
    private Applicant applicant;
```

and

```
public class Applicant {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "number", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String number;
```

please help me. How create criteria for get me data for this query: `select applicant.number from black_list inner join applicant on black_list.applicant_id = applicant.id`

```
  public  List<BlackList> getAll(){
        Session session =sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        ProjectionList projectionList = Projections.projectionList();
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(BlackList.class);
        projectionList.add(Projections.property("applicant"));
        criteria.setProjection(projectionList);
        List res = criteria.list();
        return  res;
    }
```

this method returned me /id and number/ but i need only number

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways to approach this, you could select the applicants from the black list using hql.Or you could add the inverse join in your applicant, allowing you to 'create alias' and add a 'not null' restriction.

Comment: could we help me to write this?